# Fill dynamically a <select> from JSON array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

for my project I'm trying to create a dynamic product sheet and by now I can't fill the  field from my JSON.

Here's my JS

```
 //Creating Select
const createOptionField = document.createElement("select")
createOptionField.id = 'select-options'
createOptionField.classList.add("product-options", "product-sheet-infos")
createContainer.appendChild(createOptionField)

//Generating Option
const createOption = document.createElement('option')
createOption.value = "default"
createOptionField.appendChild(createOption)

//Fill options with JSON array
const select = document.getElementById("select-options")
const options = article.lenses
for(var i=0; i<options.lenght; i++)
        {   
            
            var option = document.createElement("Option"),
                inner = document.createTextNode(options[i])

                option.appendChild(inner);

            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild)
```

}

Here's my array within my Json

```
Array(3) [ "50mm 1.8", "60mm 2.8", "24-60mm 2.8/4.5" ]
```

​

I don't have any error in my console and I don't know where the issue's coming from

Comment: What have you done so far to try and debug this then? Have you verified it actually enters into that `for` loop at least?

Comment: (FYI, there is an easier/less convoluted way to create option elements, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

Comment: You're creating a new `select` when you already appear to have one in the HTML. That's confusing. And you have a typo with "lenght". This also has nothing to do with NodeJS.

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved when the `lenght` typo is fixed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this it should help in your situation [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amirrahman132132/4re86tda/)

```
var selectEl = document.querySelector(".select"),
    data = ["one","two","three"]

loadFromJson(selectEl,data)

function loadFromJson(el,json){
  // appending options from json 
  json.forEach(each=>{
    var newEl = document.createElement("option")
    newEl.innerText = each
    newEl.value = each
    el.appendChild(newEl)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy Michel,
I have done some modifications to your code.
and its working fine.

You just need to do some correction in loop and `options.length`

```
const createOptionField = document.createElement("select")
createOptionField.id = 'select-options'
createOptionField.classList.add("product-options", "product-sheet-infos")
// use your container createContainer
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(createOptionField)

//Generating Option
const createOption = document.createElement('option');
createOption.value = "default";
createOption.text='default';
createOptionField.appendChild(createOption);



//Fill options with JSON array
const select = document.getElementById("select-options")
// consider this as your array 
const options = [ "50mm 1.8", "60mm 2.8", "24-60mm 2.8/4.5" ];
for(var i=0; i< options.length; i++){   
           
           //Createing single option with text and value
            var option = document.createElement("option");
                
                option.value = options[i];
                option.text= options[i];

            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild)
}
```